# How to map a virtual desktop to a monitor in a multiple monitor setup?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

OS: Microsoft Windows Vista SP2, Microsoft Windows 7

My laptop is plugged to a docking station that supports dual monitors, which I use extensively. I have windows placed where I want them. All is well and predictable with this setup until I un-dock.

The moment I un-dock all windows that I placed in the secondary monitor piles up in the primary monitor and it is an unholy mess.

So, I am looking for a solution where if I use virtual desktops, one of them can be mapped to a monitor and when un-docked what was there in the secondary monitor stays in a virtual desktop. Do you folks know of a tool or workaround that can address my quandary?

Comment: do you have auto arrange turned on? or can you drag icons around the desktop freely on a grid? have you tried playing with the auto arrange settings? I use DisplayFusion and don't have this issue.

Comment: http://www.displayfusion.com/ I don't know if it will work but give it a try, it has free 30 day Pro trial license key!

Answer (score 1):

Dexpot is a virtual desktop tool that allows for window placement rules and profiles.

My suggestion would be to get this app, set it to have 2 desktops, make a profile for when you're docked, so that all windows show on vdesktop 1 and another so that half of these windows show on 1 and the other half on 2.

I know it's not exactly what you're asking for, since you have to predefine which windows go to vd 1 and which go to vd2, instead of having all of the windows on the right screen go to vd 2, but it's probably as close as you'll get. I'm quite sure there isn't an app that makes vdesktops that span only one screen at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Dual Monitor Tools which you can pick up from Soruceforge.net.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortool/

Answer (score 0):

Check out UltraMon.  It has some good features for managing multiple desktops if you're willing to deal with the overhead. (It's not bad for overhead I'm just running a lot on poor hardware so streamlining is my best bet.)  I'm not 100% sure it'll do what you're after but it is fairly configurable.

Comment: UltraMon does not apply for my use case.

Comment: Yeah, UltraMon won't do this sadly.